# Overrriding destructor of std:exception

Tags: c++, exception, destructor, throw

The following program does not compile in g++ 4.4 if `line 8` is commented. Why? It seems that when I override `std::exception` constructor, I must override its destructor as well. What's the reason for this?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<exception>
using namespace std;

class A : public exception {
public:
    A(string msg) : _msg(msg) {}
    //~A() throw(){};                     // line 8
    const char* what() const throw() { return _msg.c_str();}    
private:
    string _msg;
};

int main()
{
}
```

The compilation error is:

```
error: looser throw specifier for ‘virtual A::~A()’
```

Comment: Does the compiler report an error message? And if so, why is it not in the question?

Comment: It is in his question at the bottom (might be after editing though). It is the same with 4.8.1 of course because the default destructor will not have throw specifier which is requested in here.

Comment: @Laszlo Yes, it's in the question after it was edited and the error added

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because the destructor requires a throw() specifier. If you don't specify it in your class the compiler writes it's own default destructor for you class, and the default destructor doesn't specify that you don't throw exceptions.

This is correct, since the public destructor of std::exception also specifies `throw()`

```
~A() throw(){};
```

from the standard (N3225) 12.4.4 :

> If a class has no user-declared destructor, a destructor is implicitly declared as >defaulted (8.4). An implicitly-
>   declared destructor is an inline public member of its class.

Therefore, if you don't declare the destructor yourself the compiler creates the next destructor. If all your exception member destructors where `nothrow` qualified, the compiler will probably generate a destructor with `throw()` specified.

```
~A(){};
```

And technically one could throw an exception from this destructor, but that would be very bad programming style, therefore an exception deriving from `std::exception` guarantees that you don't throw any exceptions in the destructor of a `std::exception` derived class.

**Edit**
Newer compilers will provide a destructor that does have a `noexcept` specifier if the destructor of std::string is `noexcept` specified. And other compilers will also generate a `noexcept` destructor if all member's destructors don't throw exceptions (are noexcept qualified).
This is mandated by C++11 standard in chapter 15.4. [except.spec]

> 14 An implicitly declared special member function (Clause 12) shall have an exception-speciﬁcation. **If f is
>   an implicitly declared default constructor**, copy constructor, move constructor, destructor, copy assignment
>   operator, or move assignment operator, its implicit exception-speciﬁcation speciﬁes the type-id T if and only
>   if T is allowed by the exception-speciﬁcation of a function directly invoked by f’s implicit deﬁnition; f shall
>   allow all exceptions if any function it directly invokes allows all exceptions, and **f shall allow no exceptions
>   if every function it directly invokes allows no exceptions.** [...]

Comment: This isn't telling the whole story. Compiler generated destructor will have a `nothrow` specification if all the functions it directly invokes allow no exceptions (destructors of non-static data members and destructors of base classes). The example fails to compile because `std::string` member's destructor isn't marked `throw()`. Try replacing it with `const char*` and see the difference.

Comment: Both [gcc 4.8.1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0717ca903ccad574b2dea253a7ad316c-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51) and [clang 3.4](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0717ca903ccad574b2dea253a7ad316c-9f343bb235880f7057c63e887501d7f0) compile OP's code just fine. That is, in C++11. I don't know if this have been changed after C++03.

Comment: I added the normative quote from the standard, if you don't mind. And +1.

Comment: You should not highlight "nothrow" as if it were a keyword. There's a `std::nothrow` default object of type `std::nothrow_t` used for the "non-throwing `new`", but a "non-throwing exception-specification" is either `throw()` [in C++98/03, deprecated in C++11] or [in C++11] `noexcept` (or `noexcept(true)`, or any `noexcept(` _CE_ `)` where the constant-expression _CE_ evaluates to `true` (including the funny `noexcept( noexcept(` _expression_ `) )` where _expression_ can be proven at compile-time not to throw)).

Comment: @gx_ I changed nothrow in noexcept